# How do I get information out of the object returned by an iterators next() method?

Tags: java, iterator

I want to compare the destination variable (type int) of a person object with the current floor variable (type int) of a lift object. The person objects are located in a ListArray that belongs to the Lift class. I am using the iterator interface to iterate over the ListArray to compare each persons destination with current floor of the lift. The method match(int destination) is used to return true or false.

This is my code that does not work:

```
Iterator iterator = lift.getOccupants().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
  if(lift.match(iterator.next().getDestination())){
  }
```

The `getDestination()` method is underlined with the error:

> cannot find symbol, method getDestination(), location class Object

Comment: Java 5 is almost 10 years but it seems people are still reading Java books from the 90s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameterize the iterator and this will work for you

```
    Iterator<Person> iterator = lift.getOccupants().iterator(); 
    while(iterator.hasNext()){ 
       if(lift.match(iterator.next().getDestination())){ 
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`next()` method return type is Object so you need to type cast it to `Person` object.
Like

```
((Person)iterator.next()).getDestination()
```

Or else you can use Generic List objects like List and get Generic iterator through it.

```
Iterator<Person> iterator = lift.getOccupants().iterator();
```

Then you do not need any casting.

Comment: Thanks casting makes sense! However now I have an error where the ((Person)iterator.next()) in the line: if(lift.match((Person)iterator.next()).getDestination()) stating "incompatible types: LiftSimulator.Person cannot be converted to int

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Iterator<Occupant> iterator = lift.getOccupants().iterator();
```

The proper idiom involving the `Iterator` is not a `while`, but a `for`-loop:

```
for (Iterator<Occupant> it = lift.getOccupants().iterator; it.hasNext();)
  if (lift.match(it.next().getDestination())) it.remove();
```

The advantage of this is keeping the scope of `it` contained.

Comment: using a for each loop was my first approach but because I then remove person objects from the ListArray while still iterating over it, it produces a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus using the iterator interface is my next approach. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 `Stream`:

```
lift.getOccupants().stream()
                   .filter(o -> lift.match(o.getDestination()))
                   // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Generics** in java like this:

```
  Iterator<Person> iterator = lift.getOccupants().iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext()){  
  if(lift.match(iterator.next().getDestination())){   }
```